# Is there a monero address monitoring service?

Tags: watch-only-wallet

Is there a monero monitoring service where it will email/sms me if it receives any coins? I'm assuming you'd have to give this service your public view and public spend keys in order for them to see anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none so far. You'd need to give it also your **private** view key, and it would have to spend some CPU resources to keep scanning. I assume that's one of the reasons nobody created such service.

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to use view-only wallet and some soft for scan and notificate youby email or sms.

Comment: If you are aware of the existence of this type of notification software, please amend your answer to include the details